# selector inside jquery .next() method is not selecting correct element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added two divs using jquery.I use corresponding selector inside jquery .next()  to target them. I always get second div.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <p class = 'myp'>this is my p</p>
</body>
```

jquery:

```
    $(function(){
      $('p.myp').after('<div class = "firstDiv">first div added with jquery</div>');
      $('p.myp').after('<div class = "secondDiv">second div added with jquery</div>');
      console.log($('p.myp').next('div.firstDiv').text());

      console.log($('p.myp').next('div.secondDiv').text());
    });
```

jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/lomol/4/edit

Comment: There is no element with class `firstDiv` next to `p` element. next() only check for first following element. Use maybe siblings() instead

Comment: @A.Wolff .siblings() is answer to my question . I had some misunderstanding about the selector inside .next() as I mentioned below .

Answer (score 2):

`next()` selects ***only*** the next element, the selector passed is just a filter, it doesn't search any further than the next immediate sibling.

When you use `after()` twice, the first element inserted is pushed down, so it's no longer the next immediate element, the markup you end up with is

```
<body>
  <p class="myp">this is my p</p>
  <div class="secondDiv">second div added with jquery</div> <!-- this is next -->
  <div class="firstDiv">first div added with jquery</div> <!-- this is not -->
</body>
```

There are many other ways to get the element, using an ID, creating the elements with a reference etc.

```
$(function () {
    var first = $('<div />', {
        'class' : 'firstDiv',
        text    : 'first div added with jquery'
    });
    var second = $('<div />', {
        'class' : 'secondDiv',
        text    : 'second div added with jquery'
    });

    $('p.myp').after(first);
    $('p.myp').after(second);

    console.log(first.text());
    console.log(second.text());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4NMf/)

Comment: According to http://api.jquery.com/next/  the syntax is .next( [selector ] ) .If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector. It misunderstood it. I thought it will select from all next siblings and filter based upon the selector passed inside .next().But actually without using selector it will return immediate next sibling and when we pass selector inside .next() then still it will return only immediate next sibling but if matches selector. Please correct me if I wrong.

Comment: @Triven You are correct. Now if you want only next siblings unregarding it is the direct next one or not (and return only one), other solution could be: `$('p.myp').nextAll('div.firstDiv').first().text()`, even in your case this would be enough: `$('p.myp').nextAll('div.firstDiv').text()` or ya, use `.siblings('div.firstDiv').text()`

Answer (score 1):

Which is not surprising as `secondDiv` will always be the next element. You may see how it works:

1. Initially you have the following markup:

   ```
   <p class="myp">this is my p</p>
   ```
2. Then you insert `firstDiv` after `p.myp`:

   ```
   $('p.myp').after('<div class="firstDiv"></div>');
   ```

   And your markup becomes the following:

   ```
   <p class="myp">this is my p</p>
   <div class="firstDiv"></div>
   ```
3. Then you insert `secondDiv` after `p.myp`:

   ```
   $('p.myp').after('<div class="secondDiv"></div>');
   ```

   And your markup becomes:

   ```
   <p class="myp">this is my p</p>
   <div class="secondDiv"></div>
   <div class="firstDiv"></div>
   ```

From the above you may see that `secondDiv` now is the next element after `<p>`.